# How can Python differentiate that the indentation is with 2, 3 or 4 spaces?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Code and it has an option to choose with how many spaces the user wants to indent, but how does Python knows that the user is indenting with 2 or 4 spaces? It sees a pattern of "N" spaces and then it follows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually fairly complicated - you can read exactly how it works in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation).

But yes, it essentially uses the first indent that it sees (in a spot where an indent is required) and uses that as the expected indentation level for that block. But you are allowed to mix-and-match indentation levels in different blocks, including nested blocks, as long as each block is consistent.

Comment: Also, you can use the `tokenize` module to see the `INDENT` and `DEDENT` tokens generated to represent relative levels of indentation in a piece of Python code. (Each time a line is correctly indented relative to the preceding line, a new `INDENT` token with the actual whitespace used is generated. When line is correctly dedented, a `DEDENT` token is generated. That's all the information the *parser* needs to parse Python; the actual amounts of whitespace are irrelevant.